# This expression was expected to have type string -> int but here has type int

Tags: f#

Sorry if this question is really silly, just started to get my feet wet with F# (Coming from C#).

Suppose I have following:

```
1: let Foo (names : string[]) =
2:    let favNames : string[] = 
3:        Array.filter(fun name -> name.StartsWith("M")) names
4:    let sortByLengthOfName (x : string) : int = x.Length       
5:    let sortedNamesByLegth : string[] = 
6:        Array.sortWith(fun name -> fun n -> n.Length) favNames
7:    Array.iter(fun name -> printfn "%s" name) sortedNamesByLegth
```

Here I'm trying to define/(declare?) a function `Foo` which will accept array of strings (names) and perform the following:

1. Filter array by returning only names that start with M
2. Sort by length of the name
3. Print out the results

Now this almost works (except of sorting part, it doesn't sort at all, which is fine for now) but I'm confused with following - if I replace lines #5, 6 with following:

```
let sortedNamesByLegth : string[] = 
    Array.sortWith(fun name -> sortByLengthOfName name) favNames
```

Compiler starts to complain with `This expression was expected to have type string -> int but here has type int`. Now this is confusing for me because `sortByLegnthOfName` to me is `string -> int`. I tried something along these lines

```
let sortedNamesByLegth : string[] = 
    Array.sortWith(fun name -> (sortByLengthOfName name)) favNames
```

But I'm still getting the same message.

Can anyone please explain what is wrong here? What's the difference between compiling one and non-compiling? And more importantly, where can I read more about this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function for sortwith this signature

```
Array.sortWith : ('T -> 'T -> int) -> 'T [] -> 'T []
```

Your lambda then needs to have a signature of

```
('T -> 'T -> int)
```

but yours is just

```
'T -> int
```

You probably want `sortBy` instead as sortwith needs a comparer function