# f# - This expression was expected to have type int but here has type 'a -> int

Tags: f#

I'm tried to work with function in f# but I found one problem now.

I created the function to add number in the array and file txt but the Visual Studio say me that have one error in my code.

The function is:

```
let fnAddNodeFileAndArray (pstrnode:string) lintRowResult:int = 

//Declare variables
let mutable lstrText = ""
let mutable larrColisionsAux = Array2D.zeroCreate 0 0
let mutable lintIndexOfSpace = 0
let mutable lstrfirstNumber = ""
let mutable lstrsecondNumber = ""
let mutable lintNumberColisionNetwork = 0
let mutable lblnCollisionExist = false
let mutable lintRowResultAux=0

//Identify the position where the separator
lintIndexOfSpace<-pstrnode.IndexOf(",")
//Get nodes of the collision
lstrfirstNumber<-(pstrnode.Substring(0,lintIndexOfSpace))
lstrsecondNumber<-(pstrnode.Substring(lintIndexOfSpace + 1))

for lintRow = 0 to garrrows - 1 do
    let mutable lintNumberAux1 = int garrColisions.[lintRow,0]
    let mutable lintNumberAux2 = int garrColisions.[lintRow,1]    
    if (string lstrfirstNumber = string  lintNumberAux1 && string lstrsecondNumber = string lintNumberAux2) ||
        (string lstrfirstNumber = string lintNumberAux1 && string lstrsecondNumber = string lintNumberAux2) then
        lblnCollisionExist <- true

if lblnCollisionExist=true then
    printfn ""
    printfn "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
    printfn "Node already exist."
    printfn "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"   
    lintRowResultAux
else    

    //Copy the values of the array to auxiliar array
    larrColisionsAux<-garrColisions

    //Update de number of collisions
    garrrows <- garrrows + 1

    //Re-Create array
    garrColisions <- Array2D.zeroCreate garrrows 3 

    for lintRow = 0 to garrrows - 2 do
        garrColisions.[lintRow,0] <- larrColisionsAux.[lintRow,0]
        garrColisions.[lintRow,1] <- larrColisionsAux.[lintRow,1]
        garrColisions.[lintRow,2] <- larrColisionsAux.[lintRow,2]

    //Save the new Number in auxiliar Array
    garrColisions.[(garrrows-1),0] <- string lstrfirstNumber
    garrColisions.[(garrrows-1),1] <- string lstrsecondNumber

    //Save the number in the file
    for lintCount = 0 to garrrows-1 do
        lstrText <- lstrText + garrColisions.[lintCount,0] + " " + garrColisions.[lintCount,1] + "\n"
    File.WriteAllText(gstrpath,lstrText)

    for lintRow = 0 to (garrrows - 2) do    
        let mutable lintNumberAux1 = int garrColisions.[lintRow,0]
        let mutable lintNumberAux2 = int garrColisions.[lintRow,1]    
        let mutable lintNumberCollisionNetworkAux = int garrColisions.[lintRow,2]
        let mutable lblnLessOneNumberOfTheCollisionNetwork = false

        if (lstrfirstNumber <> string lintNumberAux1 ) && 
           (lstrsecondNumber <> string lintNumberAux2) &&
           (lstrfirstNumber <> string lintNumberAux2) && 
           (lstrsecondNumber <> string lintNumberAux1) then
            if lintNumberColisionNetwork = 0 then
                gintNumberColisionNetwork <- gintNumberColisionNetwork + 1
                garrColisions.[(garrrows-1),2] <- string (gintNumberColisionNetwork)
        elif ((lstrfirstNumber = string lintNumberAux1) && (lstrsecondNumber <> string lintNumberAux2)) || 
               ((lstrfirstNumber <> string lintNumberAux1) && (lstrsecondNumber = string lintNumberAux2)) ||
               ((lstrfirstNumber <> string lintNumberAux2) && (lstrsecondNumber = string lintNumberAux1)) || 
               ((lstrfirstNumber = string lintNumberAux2) && (lstrsecondNumber <> string lintNumberAux1)) then
            if lintNumberColisionNetwork < lintNumberCollisionNetworkAux then
                garrColisions.[(garrrows-1),2] <- garrColisions.[lintRow,2]
                if lintNumberColisionNetwork <> 0  && lblnLessOneNumberOfTheCollisionNetwork = false then
                    gintNumberColisionNetwork <- gintNumberColisionNetwork - 1
                    lblnLessOneNumberOfTheCollisionNetwork <- true
                lintNumberColisionNetwork <- int garrColisions.[lintRow,2]
            elif lintNumberColisionNetwork > lintNumberCollisionNetworkAux then
                garrColisions.[lintRow,2] <- garrColisions.[(garrrows-1),2]
                if lintNumberColisionNetwork <> 0 && lblnLessOneNumberOfTheCollisionNetwork = false then
                    gintNumberColisionNetwork <- gintNumberColisionNetwork - 1
                    lblnLessOneNumberOfTheCollisionNetwork <- true
                lintNumberColisionNetwork <- int garrColisions.[lintRow,2]
    garrrows

let fnAddnode () =

    let mutable lintrow = 0
    let mutable lstrNode = ""

    lstrNode <- fnGetNewNode()
    lintrow <- fnAddNodeFileAndArray(lstrNode)
    fnPrintCollisionOneNode (lintrow)
```

When I try to call the function the system show this messagem:

> This expression was expected to have type int but here has type 'a ->
>   int

Someone know what it's mean??

Comment: Typically when you have errors like `expected to have type <value> but here has type <function>` it means you did not pass a parameter to a function.

Comment: If you are leaning F# and functional programming you should avoid using `mutable`. I know it is hard at first but you should avoid it when starting out as it will only slow you down in learning and it is not considered functional. The only time I use mutables is when I am using [P/Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh304361(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: There are many duplicates: e.g. [This expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321963/this-expression-was-expected-to-have-type-string-int-but-here-has-type-int?s=2|3.7914) It means that something was supposed to be a number but is instead a function.

Comment: what happens if you put a parenthesis around (lintRowResult:int) in your first row...like this `let fnAddNodeFileAndArray (pstrnode:string) (lintRowResult:int) =`

Comment: Please, post where the error message points you - it saves us a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over `let fnAddNodeFileAndArray (pstrnode:string) lintRowResult:int =` you will notice that the type signature is the following:

> val fnAddNodeFileAndArray : pstrnode:string -> lintRowResult:'a -> int

This means a function that takes string, returns a function taking a lintRowResult, then finally returns an int. Because you didn't put paranthesis around lintRowResult, F# thinks you are annotating the return type of the function, and not the input type of the parameter. Probably you wanted to say something like this:

`let fnAddNodeFileAndArray (pstrnode:string) (lintRowResult:int) =`

The type signature of this function than will become:

> val fnAddNodeFileAndArray : pstrnode:string -> lintRowResult:int ->
>   int

This is a function taking a string and an int, then returning an int. So it has two parameters. Now if you go to the penultimate line in your code: `lintrow <- fnAddNodeFileAndArray(lstrNode)` you only have one parameter. So probably you would need to write something like:
`lintrow <- fnAddNodeFileAndArray lstrNode lintRow`

Now obviously your `fnAddNodeFileAndArray` function might be a function that just needs an `lstNode`, in that case leave off the `lintRowResult` input parameter:
`fnAddNodeFileAndArray (pstrnode:string)`:

> val fnAddNodeFileAndArray : pstrnode:string -> int

You can see that F# knows that output type of the function.

You should probably take @GuyCoder's comment seriously about defining mutables everywhere. The code reads very imperative, like python via google translator...You could maybe post it on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) It is also fairly long and contains external references, and other errors. You will have better luck with a smaller self-contained example, see: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)